# history/favourite feature iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, history, nsuserdefaults, favorites

For my current development of iphone app, I want to implement history/favorite feature. After lots of googling I came to conclusion that 'NSUserDefaults' would work better in case of short data storage. But still I am not clear how to interact with NSUserDefaults....Can anyone refer any example or article to work out with this requirement? Help appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

And here it is an example on how to use it:

```
// Saving info to defaults
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:myObj forKey:@"myKey"];

// Retrieving info from defaults
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Depending on the kind of info that you want to store, you may be interested on have a look at [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and use it to encode your objects before save them on the user defaults, or any other place.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html) is only for Application Setting. This is the recommendation from Apple. You should consider it carefully.

> This programming topic describes the
>   programmatic interface for interacting
>   with the Mac OS X user preferences
>   system—also known as the user defaults
>   system—using Cocoa. Preference
>   settings let you offer ways for users
>   to customize the appearance or
>   behavior of your software. The user
>   defaults system lets you access and
>   manage user preferences. You can use
>   the defaults system to provide
>   reasonable initial values for
>   application settings, as well as save
>   and retrieve the user's own preference
>   selections across sessions.